# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object, when I try to delete a user in admin with a superuser

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

I created a custom user model and now when I try to delete a user in the admin interface as a superuser I am getting this `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object error`. The probmlem just after creating a custom user.
Someone help me please. I have been stuck on it for some time now and now I really want to just fix it.

Here is my models.py file:

```
class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password, 
    **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_verified', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, first_name, last_name, password, 
        **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide an email address'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, 
        **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


 class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    
        email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
        objects = CustomAccountManager()
    
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    
        def get_full_name(self):
            return f"{self.first_name}-{self.last_name}" 
    
        def get_first_name(self):
            return self.first_name
       
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.email
```

Admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from users.models import UserAccount
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.forms import Textarea
from django.db import models


class UserAdminConfig(UserAdmin):
    model = UserAccount
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    list_filter = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 
    'is_verified')
    ordering = ('-start_date',)
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name','last_name',
                    'is_active', 'is_staff','is_verified')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'first_name','last_name')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_verified')}),
        ('Personal', {'fields': ('about',)}),
    )
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows': 20, 'cols': 60})},
    }
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2', 
    'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_verified')}
         ),
    )


    admin.site.register(UserAccount, UserAdminConfig)
```

This the traceback message.

```
 File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/main/models.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.__initial_first_name = self.first_name
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query_utils.py", line 182, in __get__
    instance.refresh_from_db(fields=[field_name])
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 722, in refresh_from_db
    db_instance = db_instance_qs.get()
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 646, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 376, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1867, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 118, in __iter__
    obj = model_cls.from_db(
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 580, in from_db
    new = cls(*values)
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/main/models.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.__initial_last_name = self.last_name
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query_utils.py", line 182, in __get__
    instance.refresh_from_db(fields=[field_name])
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 722, in refresh_from_db
    db_instance = db_instance_qs.get()
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 646, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 376, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1867, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 118, in __iter__
    obj = model_cls.from_db(
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 580, in from_db
    new = cls(*values)
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/main/models.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.__initial_first_name = self.first_name
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query_utils.py", line 182, in __get__
    instance.refresh_from_db(fields=[field_name])
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 705, in refresh_from_db
    db_instance_qs = self.__class__._base_manager.db_manager(
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1421, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1439, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1446, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1532, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1562, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1478, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1303, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 341, in get_prep_lookup
    return super().get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 85, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/home/enoch/REPOS/my-projects/Exodt/exodt-backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2014, in get_prep_value
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
HTTP POST /admin/users/useraccount/ 500 [165.43, 127.0.0.1:47182]
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

Comment: My apologies, added the traceback now. @JohnGordon

Comment: It looks like the error is happening in a part of `models.py` that you haven't shown us.  Can you include that whole module in the question?

Comment: The line `self.__initial_first_name = self.first_name`  isn't in this model, It's in a model in another app which this user model have a one to one relationship with  and I had forgoten about it and wasn't even looking in that model until you pointed this out. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I just fixed it and everything is working fine now. Lesson learned, will thoroughly look and pay more attention to the traceback messege next time :). @JohnGordon